# Incompatibility when using polish characters

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace a string with polish characters.

I tried the following code:

```
k = 'aąkkk cdkkk aą xskkk'
odp = re.sub('(?<!aą|cd)kkk', '***', k)
print (odp)
```

But unfortunately it produces the following error:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile raise error, v # invalid expression

The problem is with **polish characters** because when I replace the 'ą' character with 'a' char it works fine:

```
k = 'aąkkk cdkkk aą xskkk'
odp = re.sub('(?<!aa|cd)kkk', '***', k)
print (odp)
```

The answer is: `aą*** cdkkk aą xs***`

I tried using UNICODE but it still doesn't work:

```
a = re.compile(ur'(?<!\u0061\u0105|\u0063\u0064)kkk', re.UNICODE)
a
k = u'aąkkk cdkkk aą xskkk'
odp = a.sub('***', k)
print (odp)
```

The answer to the above is: `aÄ*** cdkkk aÄ xs***`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you setting `coding:` at the beginning of your script? The result looks like you need to enable UTF-8 support in your terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want the result to be. If you want `'aą*** cdkkk aą xs***'`, then you can do this:

```
>>> k = u'aąkkk cdkkk aą xskkk'
>>> re.sub(u'(?<!(aą|cd))kkk', '***', k, re.UNICODE)
'aąkkk cdkkk aą xs***'
```

Comment: no, I want to replace all substrings 'kkk', but not starts with aą and cd, so it should be:

    'aąkkk cdkkk aą xs***

or if 

    k = u'aąkkk kkk cdkkk aą xskkk' 
the reason should be:

    'aąkkk *** cdkkk aą xs***'

Comment: @qwertymz ok, I edited my answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: It's strange situation. Now I saw that my code don't want to compile in WingIde app, but in python shell it works.
Than you for your help, because when you show me that your code is working, but it wasn't working in WingIde, then I tried to make in python shell and it work :) Thank's again